# Qt and Arduino serial communication (Read and Write)

Tags: c++, qt, interface, arduino, serial-port

I am stuck with a very simple problem.

I am trying to make a Qt GUI application to control my Arduino from the GUI (instead of controlling it from the serial monitor of Arduino IDE). I am able to successfully Write to Arduino with QSerialPort write() method, but I am unable to read anything from the Arduino. The only way I can read from the serial port is by using waitForReadyRead(5000) after the write() function in waitForBytesWritten() in my Qt code. But I have to use a 5000 ms time interval to read successfully, which is time taking. Please let me know if there is any faster way of reading Arduino serial port in my Qt GUI application.

I am posting my Qt and Arduino code.

**Qt Code**

```
#include "GuiApp.h"
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

GuiApp::GuiApp(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ui.lcdNumber_temp->display("--------");
    arduino = new QSerialPort(this);

    bool arduino_available = false;
    QString arduino_portName;


    foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        if (serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier() && serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier()) {
            if ((serialPortInfo.productIdentifier() == arduino_pid) && (serialPortInfo.vendorIdentifier() == arduino_vid)) {
                arduino_available = true;
                arduino_portName = serialPortInfo.portName();
            }
        }
    }

    //qDebug() << "Number of ports" << QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts().length() << "\n";
    //foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
    //  qDebug() << "Description" << serialPortInfo.description() << "\n";
    //  qDebug() << "Has Vendor Id?" << serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier() << "\n";
    //  qDebug() << "Vendor Id" << serialPortInfo.vendorIdentifier() << "\n";
    //  qDebug() << "Has Product Id?" << serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier() << "\n";
    //  qDebug() << "Product Id" << serialPortInfo.productIdentifier() << "\n";
    //}


    if (arduino_available) {
        arduino->setPortName(arduino_portName);
        arduino->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
        arduino->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        arduino->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        arduino->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        arduino->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
        arduino->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        if (!arduino->isOpen()) {
            qDebug() << "Arduino Not Opening";
        }
        QObject::connect(ui.pushButton_connect,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(button_pressed()));
        QObject::connect(arduino,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readSerial()));
        //serial.write("OK ---");
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Couldn't find correct arduino port.\n";
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Serial Port Error","Couldn't open serial port to arduino.");
    }
}

GuiApp::~GuiApp()
{
    //serial.close();
    if (arduino->isOpen()) {
        qDebug() << "Arduino Closed!\n";
        arduino->close();
    }
}

void GuiApp::button_pressed() {
    if (arduino->isWritable()) {
        arduino->write("255");
        arduino->waitForBytesWritten(5000);

        //QByteArray s = arduino->readAll();
        //arduino->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        //std::string str = s.toStdString();
        //qDebug("My String %s", str);

    }
    else {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Serial Port Error", "Couldn't write to Serial port.");
    }
}

void GuiApp::readSerial() {
    qDebug() << "Serial Port Works!!\n";
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Serial Port Works", "Opened serial port to arduino.");
    QByteArray serialData = arduino->readAll();
    QString temp = QString::fromStdString(serialData.toStdString());
    qDebug() << temp;
}
```

**Arduino Code**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Controllino.h>


int led = CONTROLLINO_D1;
int led2 = CONTROLLINO_D2;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2,LOW);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available()) {
     const int val = Serial.parseInt();

     if(val == 255) {
        digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        Serial.write("Ok");
     } else {
        digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
        Serial.write("Not Ok");
     }

  }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use *QSerialPort::onReadyRead()*? Create a member slot function of your *GuiApp* class and connect the serialport object's signal to it.

Comment: @markus-nm I have a slot already GuiApp::readSerial()

Comment: My bad, didnt see that. Any chance you are using Qt 5.13.1? Theres a bug concerning the *readyRead()* signal not being fired unless you explicitly call *waitForReadyRead()*. In this case you can either repeatedly call *waitForReadyRead(0)* to work around this, or upgrade to Qt 5.14.

Comment: @markus-nm Thanks for the reply. My Qt version is 5.12.5. I actually did the same to make my code work after writing to the serial port. But I want to make the 'read' faster and I also want to read from the serial port first without writing to the serial port, just like a TCP CLient server system considering Arduino as the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the [QIODevice::readyRead](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal:

```
    QObject::connect(&serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, [&]() {
        standardOutput << "Recieved: " << serialPort.readAll() << endl;
    });
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25160580)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica
Sure, thanks I've just updated the answer!

Comment: @AndreaRicchi the problem  is that qt cannot catch the readyRead() signal when the arduino writes to the serial port. It only responds to the signal if qt writes to the serial port first and then issue a _qserialPort->waitForReadyRead(5000)_ function call with >5000 ms time.

Comment: Well your Arduino code is not going to send anything before it receives something. The code as you posted will start writing only after a call *Serial.available()* returns true. The Arduino reference states that *Serial.available()* will return true only after it has received data.